# Symfony expression constraint not usable in some projects

Tags: symfony

While migrating projects from Symfony 5.4 to 6.2, I noticed some (for me) inexplicable behavior. In two of the projects, I have `#[Assert\Expression()` attributes in entities, which cause this `ValidatorException`:

> Constraint validator "validator.expression" does not exist or is not enabled. Check the "validatedBy" method in your constraint class "Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Expression".

[image: Exception screenshot]

What I find mysterious about that is:

- Both projects require `symfony/validator` and `symfony/expression-language`. So far, I’ve never noticed additional requirements or necessary configuration for using `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Expression`.
- In a third project – a project created from scratch recently – the expression constraint works flawlessly. But in the project’s configuration I can’t find any reason why the constraint works here. Of the course the project uses `symfony/validator` and `symfony/expression-language`, and I did not do anything else to enable the expression constraint.

All three projects are based on PHP 8.1 and Symfony 6.2, and they all run on the very same dev machine. Additional info: I migrated the two legacy projects by creating fresh Sf 6.2 `symfony/skeleton` installations, adding requirements and then copying over code configuration from the legacy projects – while the new project was *also* created from a 6.2 `symfony/skeleton`.

Any ideas regarding the cause of the problem are welcome.

Comment: Looks like a bug of Symfony 6.2.8 ([issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/49917)), that was fixed in 6.2.9 ([pull](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/49889))

Comment: @vodevel: I’m baffled, but you’re right. The project where the expression worked was on 6.2.7, the other ones one 6.2.8 (symfony/framework-bundle). After upgrading to 6.2.9 – released less than 24h ago – it works again. Thanks.

Comment: @vodevel: why don’t you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure about this answer as the situation looked really puzzling. So I'm glad you checked it in practice and posted the guaranteed useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @vodevel pointed out, this was an issue in symfony/framework-bundle 6.2.8. Upgrading fixed the issue.